# Translate the content of a page to other language using Microsoft APIs

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online

We have a requirement to translate the content of a page or rather full page to other language for instance from English to Spanish,

I tried to use the variations available OOTB to translate but it doesn't work and only the OOTB options are translated but not the content on the page.

Is there anyway to accomplish the same using Microsoft APIs?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.Office.Client.TranslationServices;
using System.Security;

namespace testTranslate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)

        {
            ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/");
            string username = "abc@xyz.onmicrosoft.com", pssword = "";
            var securePassword = new SecureString();
            foreach (char c in pssword)
            {
                securePassword.AppendChar(c);
            }
            var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(username, securePassword);
            clientContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
            string jobID;
            string culture = "en";
            string name = "translationJob1";
            string inputFile = "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/SitePages/testTranslate.aspx";
            string outputFile = "https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/SitePages/testTranslateEnglish.aspx";
            TranslationJob job = new TranslationJob(clientContext, culture);
            job.AddFile(inputFile, outputFile);
            job.Name = name;
            job.Start();
            clientContext.Load(job);
            clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            //To retrieve the translation job ID.
            jobID = job.JobId.ToString();

            //IEnumerable<string> supportedLanguages = TranslationJob.EnumerateSupportedLanguages(clientContext);
            //clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
            //foreach (string item in supportedLanguages)
            //{
            //    Console.Write(item + ", ");
            //}
            Console.WriteLine("Script completed,press any key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Paru

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SharePoint offers a Machine Translation service at no charge, which is powered by the Microsoft Translator Text API. Learn more in the Microsoft Translator SharePoint webpage at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/sharepoint.aspx

If you are interested in using the Translator Text API, follow the steps in the Getting Started webpage at https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/getstarted.aspx . You can test the API by subscribing to the free monthly subscription tier.

Comment: i tried this and it converted my website to other language but not the content, i have added my code to the question  to translate the content but it doesn't work, can you please check what is wrong in it, i dnt get nay errors either

Comment: Link only answers are not allowed on SO. Either form your own answer or delete this altogether. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 0):

Not a SharePoint expert, but you probably need to add code to translate the actual document. Here is a link to a full document translation tool using the Microsoft Translator API:

https://github.com/MicrosoftTranslator/DocumentTranslator

Comment: Hii thanks for sharing this,  I will try it tomorrow in and see of this works for me,  but doubt is that it says it converts documents I want to convert text on a page (site page or publishing page)